# kendo ui grid add the record more than once

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo ui grid, on change row event I take the row id and pass it to another function which load other grids. I tried to simplify the operation to figure out the error like this.

HTML Code

```
<input type="button" id="load-first" value="Load 108" />    
<input type="button" id="load-second" value="Load 92" />
```

Javascript

```
$("#load-first").click(function(){
    loadEmailGrid(108);
});
$("#load-second").click(function(){
    loadEmailGrid(92);
});

  function loadEmailGrid(salesRepsId) {
      dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          transport: {
              read: {
                  url: "operations/get_emails_sales_reps.php?salesRepsId=" + salesRepsId,
                  type: "GET"
              },
              update: {
                  url: "operations/edit_email.php?salesRepsId=" + salesRepsId,
                  type: "POST",
                  complete: function (e) {
                      $("#email-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                  }
              },
              destroy: {
                  url: "operations/delete_email.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  complete: function (e) {
                      $("#email-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                  }
              },
              create: {
                  url: "operations/add_email.php?salesRepsId=" + salesRepsId,
                  type: "POST",
                  complete: function (e) {
                      $("#email-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                  }
              },
          },
          schema: {
              data: "data",
              total: "data.length", //total amount of records
              model: {
                  id: "EmailId",
                  fields: {
                      EmailType: {
                          defaultValue: {
                              EmailTypeId: 2,
                              EmailTypeName: "Home"
                          }
                      },
                      EmailText: {
                          type: "string"
                      },
                      IsMainEmail: {
                          type: "boolean"
                      },
                  }
              }

          },
          pageSize: 5,
      });
      //dataSource.sync();
      $("#email-grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: dataSource,
          height: 250,
          filterable: true,
          sortable: true,
          pageable: true,
          reorderable: false,
          groupable: false,
          batch: true,
          navigatable: true,
          toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
          editable: true,
          columns: [{
              field: "EmailType",
              title: "Type",
              editor: EmailTypeDropDownEditor,
              template: "#=EmailType.EmailTypeName#",
              filterable: {
                  extra: false,
                  field: "EmailType.EmailTypeName",
                  operators: {
                      string: {
                          startswith: "Starts with",
                          eq: "Is equal to",
                          neq: "Is not equal to"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }, {
              field: "EmailText",
              title: "Email",

          }, {
              field: "IsMainEmail",
              title: "Main?",
              width: 65,
              template: function (e) {
                  if (e.IsMainEmail == true) {
                      return '<img align="center" src ="images/check-icon.png" />';
                  } else {
                      return '';
                  }
              }
              // hidden: true

          }, {
              command: "destroy",
              title: "&nbsp;",
              width: 90
          },

          ]
      });
  }
```

an example of  return  add_email.php

> [{"EmailId":200}]

if I load the grid with one id for example I click Load 108 button. The add operation works perfectly. But when I click and mix between two buttons. ie load the grid with different id(s)
The add function called many times one with previous id and other with the clicked button id. more the mix clicking between buttons, more add function is called.

This is a [link](http://salesreps.hp.af.cm/index.php) that shows the problem.

Please, How can I fix this ? I tried many things with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use global variables, so you mix up your datasources.

Change

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({...
```

to

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({...
```

and try again.

**EDIT:**

try this as your script code.

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/9LHW5

the main thing you have to do is to separate the initialization of your grid, with the change of the transport options.

for example:

```
function loadDatasourceWithId(salesRepsId){
    var dataSourceOptions = dataSource.options; // find somehow the dataSource options
    dataSourceOptions.transport.read.url = "operations/get_emails_sales_reps.php?salesRepsId="+salesRepsId;
    dataSourceOptions.transport.update.url = "operations/edit_email.php?salesRepsId="+salesRepsId;
    dataSourceOptions.transport.create.url = "operations/add_email.php?salesRepsId="+salesRepsId

    datasource.read(); // read again to get new values to your dataSource
}
```

Comment: please check the link above, maybe you can figure something

Comment: I'll take a look. What's the problem exactly? Each button click seems to replace the old datasource fine. Can you tell me how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Inspect using firebug, load 108 grid then load load 92 grid. Try to add a new record, the add function will be called twice

Comment: try this as your script code. 
http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/9LHW5/  the main thing you have to do is to separate the initialization of your grid, with the change of the transport options.

Comment: Thank you very much. I separated initialization from changing data source. it worked fine

Comment: @Kamal Nice. I will change the initial answer so you can make it the accepted one.